# Is there any video of this (or any) successful fair catch kick?

Tags: american-football, nfl

According to Wikipedia, the last successful [fair catch kick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_catch_kick) in the NFL was made in 1976 by Ray Wersching. Is there any video of this (or any) successful fair catch kick?

Answer (score 2):

The last successful fair catch kick was made by Ray Wersching of San Diego Chargers. The kick seems to be so old that a footage of it can't be found easily online. 
But here is a video of [attempted fair catch kick](http://www.nfl.com/videos/nfl-am/0ap2000000251446/Fair-catch-free-kick-huh) with rule explanation from Dean Blandino the NFL's Vice President of officiating.

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the question.